# Using map() to iterate through a nested Prop in React

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, traversal

I'm currently using react to render a prop called `area` which looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Europe",
    "Countries": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Iceland",
        "Cities": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Selfoss"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Switzerland",
        "Cities": [{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Geneva"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Asia",
    "Countries": [{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Japan",
        "cities": [{
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Yokohama"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

UPDATE 2--

This **WORKS**:

```
 class AreaBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   }

  .....

  renderCountries() {
    return(
      <div>
        This is the country
      </div>
      )
    }

  renderContinents() {
    return(
      <div>
        This is the continent
        {this.renderCountries()}
      </div>
      )
    }

  render() {
    return(
        <div> 
            {this.renderContinents()}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
 This is the continent
 This is the country
```

Incorporating a map, this **WORKS**

```
  renderContinents(area) {
    return(
      <div>
        {area.name}
      </div>
      )
    }

  render() {
    return(
        <div> 
            {this.props.areas.map(this.renderContinents)}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
 Europe
 Asia
```

**BUT** when I include `{this.renderCountries()}`, it doesn't output anything, which I think is why I couldn't get the suggestions to work.

```
  renderCountries() {
    return(
      <div>
        This is the country          
      </div>
      )
    }


  renderContinents(area) {
    return(
      <div>
        {area.name}
        {this.renderCountries()}
      </div>
      )
    }


  render() {
    return(
        <div> 
            {this.props.areas.map(this.renderContinents)}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

On Firefox, both of the continents show up but "this is a country doesn't show up" instead I get a

```
unreachable code after return statement

When an expression exists after a valid return statement, 
a warning is given to indicate that the code after the return 
statement is unreachable, meaning it can never be run.
```

It seems like it's saying renderCountries can never be run. I'm still a bit confused about this but I think I'm going to try to separate the components and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: `.map` is an `Array` method, not `Object`'s. What do yo mean by "it doesn't work", what happens instead?

Comment: @martriay I don't get any errors in my console but nothing shows up. Also, shouldn't .map work with this because [object, object] is just an array with objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1) In the second block of code in your question, you're doing `area.countries.map`. The key on your `area` object is called `Countries`, not `countries`. `area.countries` should be undefined.

2) `area.Countries` is an array of objects, like you said in your question.  So yes, you can map over them just fine.  The problem is that each `Country` is an object, and thus, you're trying to render an object as a child of your `<div>` in your `renderCountries` function.  If you only want to display the Country's name, you should do something like this:

```
renderCountries(country){
  return(
    <div>
    {country.name}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then you will see some meaningful output.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I tried your suggestion but I think the actual mapping of area.Countries is causing some issue. I updated my code above. Thanks!

Comment: It works just fine for me.  https://jsbin.com/madosoniko/1/edit?js,output

Comment: I'm wondering if my problem is the fact I'm not using ES6 syntax, since this looks like the right answer. I updated my code one last time and I think my problem is the .map function doesn't work when I include another function call.

Comment: You can absolutely use ES5 if you want to.  I just happened to use ES6 because it's what I'm used to.  Don't feel pressured into using a syntax that you might not be comfortable with, there shouldn't be any reason why you can't use ES5 for this.

Comment: If you'd like, I can throw together a version of this that doesn't use ES6?

Comment: That would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo, use `area.Countries` instead of `area.countries`

Also I think you should create 3 components at least: `Area`, `Country` and `City`. Then you can render the data like so (please note I use ES6 syntax) :

```
var areas = [/* array you posted above*/];

// in your top-level component
render() {
 return (<div>
  {areas.map((area) => {
   return <Area data={area}/>;
  })}
 </div>);
}


// Area component
export function Area({data}) {
 render() {
  return (<div>
   Area name: {data.name}
   {data.Countries.map((country) => {
    return <Country data={country}/>
   })}
  </div>);
 }
}

// Country component
export function Country({data}) {
 render() {
  return (<div>
   Country: {data.name}
   {data.Cities.map((city) => {
    return <City data={city}/>
   })}
  </div>);
 }
}

// City component
export function City({data}) {
 render() {
  return (<div>
   City: {data.name}
  </div>);
 }
}
```

Comment: this sounds like a good approach, I haven't done much with ES6 but I'll try this one out!